# How to remove searchResultsTableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchDisplayController that displays some cells after a user has searched. After the user clicks on the cell, I am pushing a new view to my nav stack. How can I remove searchResultsTableView from the view so that when the user goes back, he doesn't see the searchResultsTableView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation of `UISearchDisplayController` it sais:

```
setActive:animated:
Displays or hides the search interface, optionally with animation.

- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated


Parameters
visible
YES to display the search interface if it is not already displayed; NO to hide the search interface if it is currently displayed.

animated;
YES to use animation for a change in visible state, otherwise NO.


Discussion
When the user focus in the search field of a managed search bar, the search display controller automatically displays the search interface. You can use this method to force the search interface to appear.

Availability
Available in iPhone OS 3.0 and later.
Declared In
UISearchDisplayController.h
```